# Do we have the feature now in B2C for MFA supporting extension numbers

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to set up MFA with extension number but I am unable to do so. Is the feature available?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "extension number"?

B2C has two phone attributes:

- "businessPhones": [],
- "mobilePhone": null,

There is also the "strongauthenticationphonenumber".

You can proof up [programmatically](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/proofing-up-users-programmatically-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-either-email-or-phone-71a71f579235) as well.

Comment: I mean when user enters their office phone is there a way to use extension number associated with office number. For e.g. 9876543210x12 where number after x represent extension number.